# How to use a digital pad of a joystick with SDL 2.0 C++

Tags: c++, sdl-2, joypad

I try to use SDL for map a joypad similar at xbox360 joypad. Now for use the button I use this code:

```
std::vector<bool> tempButtons;
                for (int j = 0; j < SDL_JoystickNumButtons(joy); j++)
                {
                    tempButtons.push_back(false);
                }
                m_buttonStates.push_back(tempButtons);
```

joy is the SDL_Joystick* and m_buttonStates is a vector.
Unfortunately this function doesn't map the 4 button of the digital pad and I don't now why...
this is my joypad:
http://www.trust.com/it-it/all-products/17518-gxt-530-dual-stick-gamepad
Thank you and sorry for my not very good english

Answer (score 1):

Thank you lago Silva, but after some test I resolved the problem with this code:

```
void InputHandler::Update() {
SDL_Event e;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
    m_keyState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    {
        switch (e.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:TheGame::Instance()->Quit(); break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:KeyboardButtonDown(); break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:KeyboardButtonUp(); break;
        case SDL_JOYAXISMOTION:JoyAxisMotion(e); break;
        case SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN:JoyButtonDown(e); break;
        case SDL_JOYBUTTONUP:JoyButtonUp(e); break;
        case SDL_JOYHATMOTION:JoyHatMotion(e); break;       //this is the code that I have implemented
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:MouseButtonDown(e); break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:MouseButtonUp(e); break;
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:MouseMotion(e); break;
        default:break;
        }
    }
}}
```

the code JoyHatMotion(e) call this function:

```
void InputHandler::JoyHatMotion(SDL_Event e){
int whichOne = e.jaxis.which;
switch (e.jhat.value)
{
case SDL_HAT_DOWN:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(1); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(0); break;
case SDL_HAT_CENTERED:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(0); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(0); break;
case SDL_HAT_LEFTDOWN:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(-1); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(1); break;
case SDL_HAT_LEFT:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(-1); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(0); break;
case SDL_HAT_LEFTUP:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(-1); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(-1); break;
case SDL_HAT_UP:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(0); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(-1); break;
case SDL_HAT_RIGHTUP:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(1); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(-1); break;
case SDL_HAT_RIGHT:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(1); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(0); break;
case SDL_HAT_RIGHTDOWN:m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Setx(1); m_joyHatValues[whichOne]->Sety(1); break;
}}
```

note that m_joyHatValues is Vector2D*

```
class Vector2D{private:
float x;
float y;
```

public:
    Vector2D(float _x, float _y) :x(_x),y(_y){}

```
float Getx(){ return x; }
float Gety(){ return y; }
void Setx(float _x){ this->x = _x; }
void Sety(float _y){ this->y = _y; }

float Length(){ return sqrt((x*x) + (y*y)); }       //la distanza dall'origine

Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D&v2)const{ return Vector2D(this->x + v2.x, this->y + v2.y); }
friend Vector2D operator+=(Vector2D& v1, const Vector2D& v2){ v1.x += v2.x; v1.y += v2.y; return v1; }
Vector2D operator- (const Vector2D&v2)const{ return Vector2D(this->x - v2.x, this->y - v2.y); }
friend Vector2D operator-=(Vector2D& v1, const Vector2D&v2){ v1.x -= v2.x; v1.y -= v2.y; return v1; }
Vector2D operator*(float scala){ return Vector2D(this->x*scala, this->y*scala); }
Vector2D& operator*=(float scala){ this->x *= scala; this->y *= scala; return *this; }
Vector2D operator/(float scala){ return Vector2D(this->x / scala, this->y / scala); }
Vector2D& operator/=(float scala){ this->x /= scala; this->y /= scala; return *this; }

void Normalize();       //porta la distanza a 0 moltiplicanto il vector2D per il suo reciproco
```

};